# Should I use the Core module Net::Ping even if it has so much failures on CPAN Testers?

Tags: perl, cpan

The [module](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aPing) `Net::Ping` seems to be a [Core module](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/Ping.html). However CPAN Testers [lists](http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/N/Net-Ping.html) hundreds of test failures for the recent version 2.41 (and also for older ones). This is surprising to me and makes me thinking if this module can be recommended for usage. Is anybody knowing a reason for this and if it is a real problem?

(At least to me this is strange since CPAN Testers is also a way to judge for a module or against. Having a Core module with so much failures kind of downgrades the name "Core module" to me...)

Comment: Sorry, this is off-topic for SO, which is for specific programming questions.  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask]

Comment: Maybe an edit helps... give me a second

Comment: You want me to look through over 200 failed test reports to decide using a core module? Well... ok. I would do this for module Foo::Bar, but I just thought for Core there are some quality standards or so...

Comment: Modules are not in Core because they have stellar quality, they are there because (a) they are needed to install other modules, (b) they have historical significance (e.g. `CGI`) or (c) because they are important for Perl to work correctly (e.g. `Carp`, `strict`, `UNIVERSAL` or `mro`). The test results you linked to are mostly from the most recent version (2.41). This CPAN version is not neccessarily the same version that was shipped with various perls as core modules (I have a 2.38 and a 2.36 version here in the installations of v16.2 / v14.2 perls).

Comment: IC... thanks a lot amon. If you like post this as an answer and I'll accept it... before the stack-community downgrades me to hell :-/

Comment: Don't read too much into the test results for a module that's fundamentally network-based.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Net::Ping` on CPAN and in perl is basically the same. The only reason why perl's own test suite most of the times passes even if Net-Ping is included is the presence of these lines in the Net-Ping tests:

```
if ($ENV{PERL_CORE}) {
  unless ($ENV{PERL_TEST_Net_Ping}) {
    print "1..0 # Skip: network dependent test\n";
      exit;
  }
```

So network tests are skipped when building and testing perl itself (in this case the `PERL_CORE` environment variable is set).

And why are so many tests failing? Sometimes a look at the corresponding analysis.cpantesters.org page helps:
http://analysis.cpantesters.org/solved?distv=Net-Ping-2.41 .
You see a series of "Can ping/reach www...." tests failing here. So apparently tests just failed because some external servers were not reachable — simply they were down, or the smoke box had network problems.

I think it's quite safe to use `Net::Ping`.